# Can we use GPT-2 sentence embedding for classification tasks?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

I am experimenting on the use of transformer embeddings in sentence classification tasks **without finetuning them**. I have used BERT embeddings and those experiments gave me very good results. Now I want to use GPT-2 embeddings (without fine-tuning). So I have two questions,

1. Can I use GPT-2 embeddings like that (because I know Gpt-2 is
   trained on the left to right)
2. Is there any example uses of GPT-2 in
       classification tasks other than generation tasks?
3. If I can use GPT-2embeddings, how should I do it?

Comment: Actually I am using Roberta. I tested the frozen Roberta embeddings for sentence sentiment classification task and it works fine even without fine tuning.

Comment: I am using Roberta embeddings and sending the average of all those embeddings, via a classification head (a fully connected layer).

Comment: As seen above, please do share code for that.

Comment: Did you able to make any progress in this? I am also wondering if I can do similar text classification using GPT-3.

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana Did you solve your problem?

Comment: yes. I will answer the question below.

Answer (score 6):

I basically solved the problem. Here I used embeddings extracted from GPT-2.

1. So yes, we can use the final token of the GPT-2 embedding sequence as the class token. Because of the self-attention mechanism from left-to-right, the final token can represent the sequential information.
2. Please check the following GitHub issue for an implementation that uses GPT-2 embeddings. [github issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3168)
3. I conducted experiments comparing GPT-2 embedding with RoBERTa embedding. I got better results only with RoBERTa embedding and not GPT-2.